# undefined method `pageless' using jquery.pageless in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll and using [jquery.pageless](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless)

But I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'pageless'`

I include jquery.pageless.js on my application.html.erb in assets:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.3.2.min', 'jquery.pageless' -%>
```

Any suggestion about how to solve this?

Comment: I dont know anything about Ruby but looking at your tag is a relative path.. probably to some default location. So Id start by making sure that jquery-1.3.2.min is actually where its supposed to be.... a simple check would be to call another method other than pageless in your include tag. If they both come back undefined, its possibly a file not found error being reported as a method not found.

Comment: I'm sure that problem is not related with javascript_include_tag. Already tested with other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using the format:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.3.2.min', 'jquery.pageless' -%>
```

in application.rb.

In assets/javascript/application.js, add those files:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jqeury.pageless
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

You need to make sure you have jquery installed:

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

then:

```
bundle install
```

Also make sure you have the jquery-pageless.js files in on of the paths mentioned in the application.js file so it gets picked up by the asset pipeline.

Comment: My mistake, it is on application.html.erb

Comment: If you use the method outlined above and then put ' <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> ' in your application.html.erb it will pick it all up from that one file. Also, if you are using an IDE like Rubymine it will alert you if the files you put in `//= require...` are visible to the application (i.e it will throw a warning if it can't find the files in the correct paths).

Comment: Can you post your application.js file?

Comment: And you have installed the query-rails gem? Where did you put the jquery.pageless.js file?

Comment: Yes, jquery-rails are installed and jquery.pageless.js is on vendor/assets/javascript. Already changed application.html.erb to <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>.

Comment: Can you post the output of the web server when you make that request? It should show the requests and what paths it is looking in for the files. I just installed the demo app from [jqeury.pageless](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless.demo), ran `bundle install` then `rake db:migrate`, then started the webserver. It's working fine.

Comment: Problem solved! I was missing application_helper which defines pageless method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Application.js file:

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
    // listed below.
    //
    // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
    // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
    //
    // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
    // compiled file.
    //
    // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
    // about supported directives.
    //
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery.pageless
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```